# Android ICS action bar buttons with text AND icon

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

In the calendar app new event form, there are two buttons in the action bar that each take up half the screen. How do I get mine to look like that?
I have hidden the app icon and the title from the bar and added the save/cancel buttons but they show up squished to the right with only icons. I have set their "showAsAction" property to be "never|withText" but the text won't show..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look directly at the source.  It uses a custom XML layout, which you can look at on the [unofficial git mirror](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/res/layout/edit_event_custom_actionbar.xml#edit).

You can set the actionBar to use this view by inflating that view and calling a simple

```
context.getActionBar().setCustomView(customView);
```